# Filter array based on filter combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have an array as following

```
array = [
{
  name: 'A'
  instructors: [
   {
     name:'InsA'
   }
  ]
  businessUnit: {name:'myBusiness'}
},
{
  name: 'B'
  instructors: [
   {
     name:'InsB'
   }
  ]
  businessUnit: {name:'myBusinessB'}
}

]
```

I want to filter this array with the values i have which are also in an array as following

```
classArr = [A,C,D]
instructorArr = [InsA,InsC,InsZ]
businessName = [myBusinessB,myBusinessX,myBusinessD]
```

NOTE: These filters can have empty arrays as well. For Ex: `businessName = []` .

My current approach is to filter as follows

```
const filtered = array?.filter(
      (activity) =>
        classArr?.includes(activity.name) &&
        activity.instructors?.some((instructor) =>
          instructorArr?.some((instructorFilter) => instructor?.name === instructorFilter),
        ) &&
        businessName?.includes(activity.businessUnit?.name),
    );
```

But the issue is this returns if all conditions are met. Not when just 2 or 1 condition is met. How can i return the filtered array when several or all conditions are met?

Comment: did you try changing `&&` to `||` in the filter function ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but it appears that you want to use OR instead of AND

Comment: looks like Akif answer is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

```
const filtered = array?.filter(
      (activity) =>
        classArr?.includes(activity.name) ||
        activity.instructors?.some((instructor) =>
          instructorArr?.some((instructorFilter) => instructor?.name === instructorFilter),
        ) ||
        businessName?.includes(activity.businessUnit?.name),
    );
```

Comment: when i do this it does not return data with filter combination. Just data matching to individual filters

Comment: can you share an example of arrays and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

In your filtered function

```
const filtered = array?.filter(
      (activity) =>
        classArr?.includes(activity.name) &&
        activity.instructors?.some((instructor) =>
          instructorArr?.some((instructorFilter) => instructor?.name === instructorFilter),
        ) &&
        businessName?.includes(activity.businessUnit?.name),
    );
```

You basically say you want to keep all activities where:
The array includes the class name
AND the array includes the instructor
AND the array includes the business unit
(the && operator is the AND operator).

However you state that you want to 'return the filtered array when several [OR] all conditions are met?'

So to fix this, you should switch out the `&&` (AND) operator with the `||` (OR) operator like this:

```
const filtered = array?.filter(
      (activity) =>
        classArr?.includes(activity.name) ||
        activity.instructors?.some((instructor) =>
          instructorArr?.some((instructorFilter) => instructor?.name === instructorFilter),
        ) ||
        businessName?.includes(activity.businessUnit?.name),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the `length` in your array. Only doing `array?` with check if its nullish, not the size.

```js
const filtered = array?.filter(
    (activity) =>
        (
            classArr.length ? classArr.includes(activity.name) : false 
        )
        && (
            activity.instructors.length  // check for length
                ? activity.instructors.some((instructor) => 
                    instructorArr.length  // check for length
                    ? instructorArr.some((instructorFilter) => instructor.name === instructorFilter)
                    : false) 
                : false
        ) 
        && (
            businessName.length ? businessName.includes(activity.businessUnit?.name) : false
        )
);
```

That line is very hard to read and will be hard for anyone else to understand in the future, so lets open it up

```js
let filtered = [];
if (array.length){
    for (const index in myArray){
        const has_classArr = !!classArr.length;
        const has_instructorArr = !!instructorArr.length;
        const has_businessName = !!businessName.length; // check for length, if you do "businessName?" it only cheks for its existence

        if (has_classArr && has_instructorArr && has_businessName){
        
            const activity = myArray[index];
            const has_activityInstructors = activity.instructors && activity.instructors.length
            const has_activityBusinessUnit = !!activity.businessUnit

            if (has_activityInstructors && has_activityBusinessUnit){
                for (const instructor of activity.instructors){
                    if (instructorArr.includes(instructor.name) && businessName.includes(activity.buninessUnit.name) && classArr.includes(activity.name))
                        filtered.push(activity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```